# How to pass global variable in javascript callback functions?

Tags: javascript, callback, global-variables

I want to pass a global variable to a javascript .each function and keep its value while the iteration.

Here is the code.

```
 var year = false;
 page.posts.each(function(item, year){
   year = true;
 });
```

The year is still false. How can year keeps its value in the iteration?

Comment: This may sound silly, but did you actually call the function?

Comment: Yes. The function will be called for each elements in page.posts.

Answer (score 1):

You have a name conflict between the function parameter and the global variable. As the function parameter name is closer to the executed code, when *JavaScript* looks up through the variable names to find out what you meant, it finds the parameter name first, so that is what becomes set.

If you want to explicitly set the global variable, you'll have to access it though `window`, i.e.

```
window.year = true; // explicit global
```

Comment: It is in fact in an ejs context, can I still use this method?

Comment: I don't know if variables from ejs are global; the other solution would be to rename your variables so you don't experience the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict in your variable names.

```
var year = false;
 page.posts.each(function(item, yr){
   year = true;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching to window document and see.

```
 window.year = false;
 page.posts.each(function(item, year){
   year = true;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can rename variable year to avoid conflict, or if you just want to change global variable , you should use window.year = true

```
page.posts.each(function(item, year){
   year = true;  
});
```